# How can i assign an associative Array without any usage of php in smarty

Tags: php, html, arrays, smarty, associative-array

I want to assign an associative array in a smarty-template.

my code s far:

```
  {assign var='bild' value=','}
  {foreach from=$bilder item=item name=foreach_assArray}
      {assign var=name value=$item->field.name}
      {assign var=bild value=['$name'=>'$item']}
    {/if}
  {/foreach}
```

I found this on: http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=79092#79092 .
Some how it doesn't work. I want the array 'bild' like a hashmap for a later usage (something like `<img src={pagr_url page=$bild.$name>`).

Does anyone have some ideas how i could get it work?

Edit: before i forget: i use Smarty2, **not** version 3

Comment: btw: the actual code gioves me an error: `syntax error: invalid attribute name: '=' ` so I know it doesn't work. ;)

Comment: {assign var=bild value=[$name=>$item]} use this without single quotes

Comment: @Manibharathi nope i get still the same syntax-error.

Comment: I think $name is null so you got the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly sure you can't do anything of the sort in Smarty 2, barring the use of `{php}{/php}` inside the template itself: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.php.tpl -- but that's not what you're looking for.

It's easy in Smarty 3 though.

The syntax in the link you provided `['foo'=>'bar',...]` is Smarty 3 syntax.